# Vim abbreviation with random results from array?

Tags: vim

Suppose I want to write a report on what I see from my window : the bus departs, Mrs Smith goes to the grocer's, etc…
An example : http://withhiddennoise.net/2010/08/12/georges-perec-an-attempt-at-exhausting-a-place-in-paris/

Of course, abbreviations are ideal for that type of shorthand. We could have :

```
:iabbr bd The bus departs
:iabbr sg Mrs Smith goes to the grocer's
```

But it is evident that these events will keep on repeating, and we are supposed not to re-use the same words (at least, not too often).

Is it possible then to have something which would look like this :

```
:iabbr bd RANDOM(The bus departs, The bus drives away, The bus takes off)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function like the following one

```
function! BD() 

  let l:t = localtime()

  if     l:t % 3 == 0
         normal aThe bus departs

  elseif l:t % 3 == 1
         normal aThe bus drives away

  else   
         normal aThe bus takes off
  endif

endfunction
```

and then declare the following `imap`:

```
:imap bd <ESC>:call BD()<CR>a
```

From now on, entering `bd` in insert mode should insert one of the three random strings.

*Edit*: As for the question if there can be multiple patterns: if I understood the question right, this is possible with something like:

```
let g:abbreviations  = [
\      ['The bus departs', 'The bus drives away', 'The bus takes off'],
\      ['foo'            , 'bar'                , 'baz'              ],
\      ['That''s ok'     , 'That''s fine'       , 'That''s good'     ],
\      ['more'           , 'less'               , 'the same'         ],
\   ]

function! ExpandAbbr(abbr_no) 

  let l:t = localtime()

  return g:abbreviations[a:abbr_no][l:t % 3]

endfunction

iabbr <expr> bd ExpandAbbr(0)
iabbr <expr> pg ExpandAbbr(1)
iabbr <expr> ok ExpandAbbr(2)
iabbr <expr> mo ExpandAbbr(3)
```

Comment: I tried your function and it worked beautifully. I rather like the idea of using the local time of the events as the random factor (and quite true to life). Now, if you allow me a subsidiary question : do I have to create 30 different functions if I have 30 different patterns, or is it possible to have 1 function that would grab - according to the :iabbr - the corresponding array out of the 30 different arrays of values (as long, of course, as these arrays only contain 3 values each) ?

Comment: it works exactly as I wished. Thanks a lot. Is there a limit (nb of columns, nb of rows) for such a matrix ? (my nested questions will stop there...)

Comment: I'd say that the limit is the memory (and maybe an index > 2^31 or so)

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to map the abbreviation to the result of the function execution, the problem here is that vim does not have random function, out of the box.

Simple example:

```
let l_position = 0

function! GetSome(the_list)
    if g:l_position >= len(a:the_list)
        let g:l_position = 0
    endif
    let result = a:the_list[g:l_position]
    let g:l_position += 1
    return result
endfunction

iabbr <expr> tt GetSome(["asdf", "afawe", "wewefsdf", "wefsdf", "jkhkljo"])
```

Now, every time you type "tt", it will substitute it for the result of GetSome() function, which cycles through the supplied list.

If you need the result to be random, you have to use [some](http://mo.morsi.org/blog/node/299) [tricks](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/simple-16-bit-random-number-generator-td2843842.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I wish to have a random result and the tricks you suggested are many levels above my competence. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: @ThG you are welcome. For best results you can combine this with the answer from Rene (localtime idea is superb) :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do that with `iabbr`, but you can do that with some templating language/extension (e.g. snipMate, here is a tutorial http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-snipmate-vim/ ). Or with setting up a function in vimscript (or any of the supported languages).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of snipMate. It most certainly exceeds my needs, but I shall eventually give it a try. As for the suggestion of a function, I have had an answer from René Nyffenegger which seems to be the one I am looking for. Thanks again.